# AWS API Gateway: API Key Limit

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-design

The AWS API Gateway by default limits the maximum number of API keys per account per region to 500, however documentation notes this can be increased by request.

Is there a hard cap on the max upper limit? Are there soft limits for which requests are unlikely to be approved? Can I get to 10K keys on the max upper end?

I'm following the [AWS developer portal setup walk-through](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/generate-your-own-api-gateway-developer-portal/) using API keys for authorization and want to ensure the project reasonably scales beyond 500.

[AWS API Gateway Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html)

Answer (score 5):

You can easily ask for an increase. But APIG has hard limit for the number of API keys. This **limit is currently 10k per region** and you cannot go beyond that.

If you need to go beyond that number, I would question if you really tend to create such a service, having 10k different users, with a potential blast radius. You might consider to split up your service into multiple APIGs to minimize the risk.

The other alternative would be create own API key mechanism. You can use Lambda authorizer [1] and store API keys let's say in the DDB.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html

Comment: how does splitting the service into multiple APIGs doesn't give us more than 10k API keys, right? unless we use APIGs from different regions?

Comment: What blast radius do you mean? API Gateway is not a single service, it's a facade to resilient and complex system. Using several endpoints there won't help, since the system is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's the ceiling regarding keys. It seems they won't tell you unless you specify your use case.
I also think that I could hit that 500 keys limit for my use case very easily.

Worst case scenario you can go multi-account, by creating a Cloud-Formation template and replicating your resources across new accounts: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html

This is not ideal, but it's one of the strategies to go around some of the limits. In your case, you will still want to have the increases for each of the new accounts. Otherwise, you will need to create 20 accounts to satisfy your requirement of 10K keys, and although AWS has a lot of tools and resources to do multi-account management (CloudFormation being one), 20 accounts would be kind of ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you have a good enough use case you can get limits increased to whatever you need as long as there is enough capacity. In this case, requiring this many keys would likely be scrutinized more since it could be a symptom of an architecture problem that could be solved differently. Like most providers, AWS would prefer you have a solid architecture for your use case so you have a great experience on their platform and also don’t abuse their platform. I’m not saying you have an architecture problem but this type of request would set off some red flags that will require strong justification.

Comment: Given my code is based on an official AWS tutorial and architecture that uses the API keys, am I likely alright? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/generate-your-own-api-gateway-developer-portal/

Comment: It all depends on your use case and what your reason is for necessitating the 10K+ keys. There might be a better way to solve the problem which is what AWS will want to understand further. Again, if there isn't a better way and you truly have 10K+ consumers that require access keys then you likely have a better chance of getting this limit increase approved. If you don't mind sharing your specific use case alternatives can be explored here.